# Sizing issue on Iphone

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-safari

I'm having some issues with the Viewport tags on my mobile site.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640">
```

Seems pretty straight forward right? I have built the site to fit an iphone screen at 640px and also have the viewport set at 640.

However it's not showing correctly on an iphone 4 or 4s.

[http://www.puffins4bicbos.co.uk/m/mobile index.html](http://www.puffins4bicbos.co.uk/m/mobile%20index.html)

It seems to be showing a large amount of grey background to the right and underneath (site is centered to the left)

I had been displaying correctly previous to this current version I have uploaded but I can't see any difference in the html.

any help would be greatly appreciated as it's driving me mad.

**OK new development.**

Sizing for mobile is fine when I access the site either directly or by going to the desktop version which auto redirects to mobile site for mobile devices.

The issue now seems to be that if I access the site from the new domain [www.bigburyapartments.co.uk](http://www.bigburyapartments.co.uk) that is forwarded to the old domain, then there are sizing issues.

i'm using domain forwarding from godaddy.com and there aren't any advanced options for me to play around with.

Anybody experienced this before? or have any idea where to look for answers?

I am certainly not against putting up some sort of splash screen with some PHP/javascript if needed to fix the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, initial-scale=1">
```

Otherwise it's hard to debug without the website code, your link doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer as I only had to apply this to the index page and then all other pages on the site were at the correct scale.

Comment: Good stuff. The initial-scale=1 tells the iPhone to display things at it's own dimensions.

Comment: @Paddy If this answer worked for you, be sure to mark it as your chosen answer so that in the future, people can quickly find what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

just use the "device-width"

read:
[Viewport Settings for Web Applications”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html)